# Can't find any servers for Datasource in SSRS/SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

So I have been working in SSRS for a while but stopped. Now having a small project in it an issue popped up.

I have SQL server and SSRS already configured from before so it should have no issue there, However in this screen I just... can't select any server because none of them appear as an option. I tried to manually input the connection string and it would give me random errors.

Here is a screenshot that shows what I mean

[image: Can't find servers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to select, just write the `servername\sqlinstance` in the text box. Then fill the sql authentication credentials or use Windows authentication.

Comment: Thank you! Its surprising something so simple isn't covered anywhere. It can get confusing